# no method matching logpdf when sampling from uniform distribution

Tags: machine-learning, julia, distribution, reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

I am trying to use reinforcement learning in julia to teach a car that is constantly being accelerated backwards (but with a positive initial velocity) to apply brakes so that it gets as close to a target distance as possible before moving backwards.

To do this, I am making use of `POMDPs.jl` and `crux.jl` which has many solvers (I'm using DQN). I will list what I believe to be the relevant parts of the script first, and then more of it towards the end.

To define the MDP, I set the initial position, velocity, and force from the brakes as a uniform distribution over some values.

```
@with_kw struct SliderMDP <: MDP{Array{Float32}, Array{Float32}}
        x0 = Distributions.Uniform(0., 80.)# Distribution to sample initial position
        v0 = Distributions.Uniform(0., 25.) # Distribution to sample initial velocity
        d0 = Distributions.Uniform(0., 2.) # Distribution to sample brake force
        ...
end
```

My state holds the values of `(position, velocity, brake force)`, and the initial state is given as:

```
function POMDPs.initialstate(mdp::SliderMDP)
    ImplicitDistribution((rng) -> Float32.([rand(rng, mdp.x0), rand(rng, mdp.v0), rand(rng, mdp.d0)]))
end
```

Then, I set up my DQN solver using `crux.jl` and called a function to solve for the policy

```
solver_dqn = DQN(π=Q_network(), S=s, N=30000)
policy_dqn = solve(solver_dqn, mdp)
```

calling `solve()` gives me the error `MethodError: no method matching logpdf(::Distributions.Categorical{Float64, Vector{Float64}}, ::Nothing)`. I am quite sure that this comes from the initial state sampling, but I am not sure why or how to fix it. I have only been learning RL from various books and online lectures for a very short time, so any help regarding the error or my the model I set up (or anything else I'm oblivious to) would be appreciated.

---

More comprehensive code:

Packages:

```
using POMDPs
using POMDPModelTools
using POMDPPolicies
using POMDPSimulators

using Parameters
using Random

using Crux
using Flux

using Distributions
```

Rest of it:

```
@with_kw struct SliderMDP <: MDP{Array{Float32}, Array{Float32}}
    x0 = Distributions.Uniform(0., 80.)# Distribution to sample initial position
    v0 = Distributions.Uniform(0., 25.) # Distribution to sample initial velocity
    d0 = Distributions.Uniform(0., 2.) # Distribution to sample brake force
    
    m::Float64 = 1.
    tension::Float64 = 3.
    dmax::Float64 = 2.
    target::Float64 = 80.
    dt::Float64 = .05
    
    γ::Float32 = 1.
    actions::Vector{Float64} = [-.1, 0., .1]
end
    
function POMDPs.gen(env::SliderMDP, s, a, rng::AbstractRNG = Random.GLOBAL_RNG)
    x, ẋ, d = s

    if x >= env.target
        a = .1
    end
    if d+a >= env.dmax || d+a <= 0
        a = 0.
    end
    
    force = (d + env.tension) * -1
    ẍ = force/env.m
    
    # Simulation
    x_ = x + env.dt * ẋ
    ẋ_ = ẋ + env.dt * ẍ
    d_ = d + a

    sp = vcat(x_, ẋ_, d_)
    reward = abs(env.target - x) * -1
        
    return (sp=sp, r=reward)
end

    

function POMDPs.initialstate(mdp::SliderMDP)
    ImplicitDistribution((rng) -> Float32.([rand(rng, mdp.x0), rand(rng, mdp.v0), rand(rng, mdp.d0)]))
end
    
POMDPs.isterminal(mdp::SliderMDP, s) = s[2] <= 0
POMDPs.discount(mdp::SliderMDP) = mdp.γ

mdp = SliderMDP();
s = state_space(mdp); # Using Crux.jl

function Q_network()
    layer1 = Dense(3, 64, relu)
    layer2 = Dense(64, 64, relu)
    layer3 = Dense(64, length(3))
    return DiscreteNetwork(Chain(layer1, layer2, layer3), [-.1, 0, .1])
end

solver_dqn = DQN(π=Q_network(), S=s, N=30000) # Using Crux.jl
policy_dqn = solve(solver_dqn, mdp) # Error comes here
```

Stacktrace:

```
policy_dqn
MethodError: no method matching logpdf(::Distributions.Categorical{Float64, Vector{Float64}}, ::Nothing)

Closest candidates are:

logpdf(::Distributions.DiscreteNonParametric, !Matched::Real) at C:\Users\name\.julia\packages\Distributions\Xrm9e\src\univariate\discrete\discretenonparametric.jl:106

logpdf(::Distributions.UnivariateDistribution{S} where S<:Distributions.ValueSupport, !Matched::AbstractArray) at deprecated.jl:70

logpdf(!Matched::POMDPPolicies.PlaybackPolicy, ::Any) at C:\Users\name\.julia\packages\POMDPPolicies\wMOK3\src\playback.jl:34

...

logpdf(::Crux.ObjectCategorical, ::Float32)@utils.jl:16
logpdf(::Crux.DistributionPolicy, ::Vector{Float64}, ::Float32)@policies.jl:305
var"#exploration#133"(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(Crux.exploration), ::Crux.DistributionPolicy, ::Vector{Float64})@policies.jl:302
exploration@policies.jl:297[inlined]
action(::Crux.DistributionPolicy, ::Vector{Float64})@policies.jl:294
var"#exploration#136"(::Crux.DiscreteNetwork, ::Int64, ::typeof(Crux.exploration), ::Crux.MixedPolicy, ::Vector{Float64})@policies.jl:326
var"#step!#173"(::Bool, ::Int64, ::typeof(Crux.step!), ::Dict{Symbol, Array}, ::Int64, ::Crux.Sampler{Main.workspace#2.SliderMDP, Vector{Float32}, Crux.DiscreteNetwork, Crux.ContinuousSpace{Tuple{Int64}}, Crux.DiscreteSpace})@sampler.jl:55
var"#steps!#174"(::Int64, ::Bool, ::Int64, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::typeof(Crux.steps!), ::Crux.Sampler{Main.workspace#2.SliderMDP, Vector{Float32}, Crux.DiscreteNetwork, Crux.ContinuousSpace{Tuple{Int64}}, Crux.DiscreteSpace})@sampler.jl:108
var"#fillto!#177"(::Int64, ::Bool, ::typeof(Crux.fillto!), ::Crux.ExperienceBuffer{Array}, ::Crux.Sampler{Main.workspace#2.SliderMDP, Vector{Float32}, Crux.DiscreteNetwork, Crux.ContinuousSpace{Tuple{Int64}}, Crux.DiscreteSpace}, ::Int64)@sampler.jl:156
solve(::Crux.OffPolicySolver, ::Main.workspace#2.SliderMDP)@off_policy.jl:86
top-level scope@Local: 1[inlined]
```

Comment: Could you post the error stacktrace? It's good you mentioned which line caused the error, but tracing the methods that lead up to the error can help a lot. As far as I can tell, the error is just that the value `nothing` was erroneously passed into `logpdf`

Comment: Added in the stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**:

Change your output vector to `Float32` i.e. `Float32[-.1, 0, .1]`.

**Long answer**:

Crux creates a `Distribution` over your network's output values, and at some point ([policies.jl:298](https://github.com/ancorso/Crux.jl/blob/master/src/policies.jl#L298)) samples a random value from it. It then converts this value to a `Float32`. Later ([utils.jl:15](https://github.com/ancorso/Crux.jl/blob/master/src/utils.jl#L15)) it does a `findfirst` to find the index of this value in the original output array (stored as `objs` within the distribution), but because the original array is still `Float64`, this fails and returns a `nothing`. Hence the error.

I believe this (converting the sampled value but not the `objs` array and/or not using approximate equality check i.e. `findfirst(isapprox(x), d.objs)`) to be a bug in the package, and would encourage you to raise this as an issue on Github.